# Regex for seperating command and parameters

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex that can match my desired format of a command. I am not very familiar with Regex, but after playing around with it, I have got some progress even though it still does not satisfy my need.

My desired command format would be: parameter flagged by `-` and value(s) of each parameter would be either single value or multi-value enclosed by `{}`. Example:

`-name Test -types {One,Two,Three}`

What I have now is this regex: `[\-][a-zA-Z0-9]*\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*` which would only satisfy, in my case, a command with single value for each parameter. For example

`-name Test -type One`

I have tried the regex `[\-][a-zA-Z0-9]*\s([a-zA-Z0-9]*|{[a-zA-Z0-9,]*})` which kind of makes sense for me. However, in reality it doesn't work. It still only matches single-value format or only the parameter part that has a multivalue.

Not sure if someone can help me to provide me an appropriate regex for my command? I am not sure why the one I have is not working.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the different param formats using an alternation, matching the list type first:

```
-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*(\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\}|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/8gLp1OsMyHEdTN).

Group 1 of each match is the option and group 2 is the parameter (if any - this regex allows for parameterless options).

---

If your language/tool supports `\w` (ie "word characters"), you can significantly improve readability by replacing every occurrence of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `\w`. Note that `\w` also matches the underscore character, but I think your pattern should too.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse the order of contents in the brackets, which is: `({[a-zA-Z0-9,]*}|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)`.

Because `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` can match an empty string, the regular expression will match it with a higher priority instead of trying to search for a curly bracket `{`.